# Neither success or error functions firing in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

At this point I need an extra pair of eyes to verify that I either am/am not crazy...

Below is my Ajax call. Seems like it's written properly. Below that is the server-side code.. again seemingly written correctly. I've placed a breakpoint in the server-side code to verify that the query has the proper data, executes, and returns what it should in the `list` object.

I've used fiddler to show that the server-side code does return a list of JSON objects, however neither the `success` or `error` callbacks are firing right now. Can anyone see something wrong with this code?

**Ajax**

```
ProductDropDown = function() {
    var lob = $("input[name='LineOfBusiness']:checked").val();
    var istate = $('#IssueState').val();

    if (lob !== undefined && istate !== '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProducts")',
            data: { lob: lob, istate: istate },
            dataType: 'json',
            succcess: function (data) {
                alert('here');

                console.log("SUCCESS");
                console.log(data);
                var markup = '';
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += '<option value="' + data[x].prevValue + '">' + data[x].Text + '</option>';
                }
                $('#Code').html(markup);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('here too');
                console.log("ERROR");
                console.log(error);
                alert('An error has occurred, please try your request again!');
            }
        });
    }
```

**C#**

```
    public JsonResult GetProducts(string lob, string istate)
    {
        using (var db = new SalesAgreementEntities())
        {
            var list = (from a in db.Product
                where a.LobID.Equals(lob) &&
                      istate.Equals("NY")
                    ? a.CompanyCode.Equals("NY")
                    : a.CompanyCode.Equals("SNY")
                select new
                {
                    ProductName = a.ProductName,
                    ClumpCode = a.CompanyCode
                }).ToList();

            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Fiddler Response (Text View)**

```
[{"ProductName":"Select 7","Code":"AW"},{"ProductName":"Select 7","Code":"U5"}]
```

Comment: Well the `success` function isn't executing because you called it `succcess`

Comment: hahahha, ok thank you :)

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typographical error.